# What does the method do model.visibilityManager.hiddenNodes?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I found a very interesting method called "model.visibilityManager.hiddenNodes". I want to hide some elements from my viewer. I am very interested in this method, about which I couldn’t find anything, so I decided to ask. It would be nice if you suggested what and how this method does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can find doc [here](https://autodesk-forge.gitee.io/helpcenter/classes/autodesk.viewing.private.visibilitymanager.html#hiddennodes) but keep in mind that's **NOT official and some of the info may be outdated and subject to change w/o notice**.

And here's some usage reference for the `visibiliyManager` component:

```
// manually restore hidden/isolated nodes of a model and apply them
var isolatedIds = this.impl.visibilityManager.getIsolatedNodes(model);
var hiddenIds   = this.impl.visibilityManager.getHiddenNodes(model);
// recover isolated/hidden nodes (Note that hiddenIds are only used if no node is isolated)
if (isolatedIds.length!=0)      viewer.impl.visibilityManager.isolate(isolatedIds, model);
else if (hiddenIds.length!=0)   viewer.impl.visibilityManager.hide(hiddenIds, model);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand this method is designed to restore isolated elements, rather than isolating them?